# ssh plus svn through php

Tags: php, svn, ssh

I am trying to run the following command through php:

```
exec("svn export svn+ssh://svn@XXXXXX/var/svn/XXXX $OUTPUT/$value2");
```

But it asks for my password each time. I have a key stored on the svn server, how can I pass pass my private key to this script to use?

Comment: Can't you use SSH-aliases? Example from ~/.ssh/config `Host 17915\n
Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\n
User login_username\n
Port 22`

Answer (score 1):

is the key which is stored in the server under the user whom is running that script?

IE normally when you log in you're logged in as "bob". However when PHP is executed, it's executed as WWW; make sure the key is stored for the proper user.